# JavaScriptSerializer - Invalid JSON Primitive

Tags: json, vb.net, class, primitive

Hello I am creating Desktop App I try to get my table show in my datagrid with source from remote sql server using PHP.

my PHP code to connecting and get the table values

```
<?php
     
        include "koneksi.php";
         
        $noresi = htmlspecialchars($_POST['NO_RESI']);
         
        if($noresi=="") {
            $rs = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM CekResi");    
        }else {
            $rs = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM CekResi WHERE NO_RESI='$noresi'");  
        }
        $rows = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)){
            array_push($rows, $row);
        }
        echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

then with desktop app button i did this for showing to my datagrid

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Private Sub btnTAMPILKAN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTAMPILKAN.Click
    Dim WF As New System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
    Dim Server As New System.Uri("http://mywebsite.com/resiapp/resi_view.php") 'URL File PHP
    Dim WC As New Net.WebClient

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

    Try
        WF.Clear()
        WF.Add("noresi", txtNORESI.Text.Trim())

        Dim RV() As Byte = WC.UploadValues(Server, "POST", WF)

        Dim JsonText As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(RV)
        Dim JSS As New JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim NomorResi = JSS.Deserialize(Of List(Of KolomResiClass))(JsonText)

        Dim BS As New BindingSource
        BS.DataSource = NomorResi

        dgCEKRESI.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        dgCEKRESI.DataSource = BS

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default

    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Informasi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End Try

End Sub
```

trying to Deserialize my class here

```
Public Class KolomResiClass
    Public Property tgl_pckp As String
    Public Property noresi As String
    Public Property nama_cust As String
    Public Property kota_pckp As String
    Public Property kota_tjn As String
    Public Property koli As String
    Public Property berat As String
    Public Property status As String
    Public Property tgl_trm As String
    Public Property vendor As String
    Public Property rincian_cst As String
    Public Property marketing As String
    Public Property cost As String
    Public Property inv_cust As String
    Public Property margin As String
End Class
```

and always got error Invalid JSON Primitive
The error come when I click the button `btnTAMPILKAN`
Please help I really want to know where is my mistakes.

Comment: How does the JSON look? Where does the error occur - on the server side (in the PHP code on post) or on the client side (in the VB code after the post request was sent)?
Shouldn't the parameter names be the same in VB and PHP - `WF.Add("noresi", ...` and `$_POST['NO_RESI']`?

Comment: "koneksi.php" is connection to database, and NO_RESI is a table column . which I want to search txtNORESI to the NO_RESI column, The error come when I click the button btnTAMPILKAN

Comment: It sounds like the JSON might be invalid.  Can you edit your question to include the actual JSON string you are trying to deserialize (the value of `JsonText`)?